# Can't boot without recovery after I installed a package to change the login screen

Tags: unity, gnome

I installed a package to change my login screen on Ubuntu 14.10

Now after installation I have noted down some major issues:

1. Booting became a problem.I have to use recovery mode to start the OS.
2. Login screen changed.

Comment: What package did you install?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @ sharad Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: @Tim I dont rememeber exactly.Otherwise wouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: okay, run the command `history`, and see if you can see it there?

Comment: @Tim I think I got it.It was a package named Slim.I just removed it.Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0):

**For 1st one**, Try **[This](https://techrax.tk/fixed-ubuntu-reboots-while-booting/)**

**For 2nd one**, Seems like Greeter Has Been Overidden. Try to do:-

```
   sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

And Find a line that looks like

`greeter-session=xxxx`

to

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

And Press F2 to save it.